# How to get chrome extension to get "full access" to all pages without requesting access on each page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[Full access and request access image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiLlI.png)

This picture shows that every time I open a new tab the extension requests access, I want to give it access to all tabs opened, like the top extension has.

Is this because I installed this extension from unpacked directory?

IF so, how can I bypass this? this is a custom extension that will not be going on the google extentionstore.

Comment: It depends on what the extension does. Either remove `activeTab` or add `"<all_urls>"` to its host permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Add: "host_permissions": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"]

To your manifest.json file, under the section of permissions. Here's a full example:

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting","tabs","storage","fontSettings","contentSettings","debugger"],
    "host_permissions": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
    "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```